# Jquery method not working to fetch the value particular key

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a  function who is containing  a list of object i am loop it through but i want value according  to the name of the key like id only .. i am unable to do so.

data in comlist--

```
[{"id":1,"companyname":"AB Information System","acronym":"ABC"},
{"id":2,"companyname":"AC Information System","acronym":"AC"}]

handleData( responseData ) { // [object Object],[object Object]
        var comlist = responseData;
      $.each(comlist, function(key, value) {
           var comlistobj = comlist[key];
        $.each(comlistobj , function(key, value) {      
             console.log(key); // if it prints for 1st iteration it prints "id"
             console.log(value); // if it prints for 1st iteration it prints 1
             console.log(value.id); // **but i want value according  to the name of the key id, it is printing undefined here**
            });
        });
    }
 });
```

Let me know if anything unclear in this.

Comment: Hey, did not follow what value are you trying to access from responseData? can you please clarify?

Comment: @cdoshi i am trying to access only id in the console see the console.log(value.id); it is i want to fetch value for id field only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid the second `$.each` loop to get the value based on the key.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var jsonResponse = [{"id":1,"companyname":"AB Information System","acronym":"ABC"}, {"id":2,"companyname":"AC Information System","acronym":"AC"}];

  $.each(jsonResponse, function( key, json ) {
    console.log(json.id)
  });
});
```

Take a look to the demo https://jsbin.com/damedigane/edit?js,console,output

Modification based on your codes:

```
[{"id":1,"companyname":"AB Information System","acronym":"ABC"},
{"id":2,"companyname":"AC Information System","acronym":"AC"}]

handleData( responseData ) { // [object Object],[object Object]
        var comlist = responseData;
      $.each(comlist, function(key, value) {

           // here value = comlist[key] is same
           var comlistobj = comlist[key];

        // Prefer to avoid this loop if you want the value based on key
        $.each(comlistobj , function(key, value) {      
             console.log(key); // if it prints for 1st iteration it prints "id"
             console.log(value); // if it prints for 1st iteration it prints 1
             console.log(comlistobj.id); // works here
            });
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: this is what i am doing if you see the question but i am getting undefined ...

Comment: it is list of objects i need two loops .... is it any other way to do ..